# Upgrading ASUS PRO50R (F5R) to windows 10 fails with error 0xC1900101 - 0x20017

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-7-upgrade

I have a question about upgrade to Windows 10.

I have an old laptop which s perfectly running Windows 7. I would like to upgrade to Windows 10, but after first stage where it copies files and it restarts, it shows Windows 10 logo, tries to boot and switches off. If switched on, it just goes back to Windows 7, showing error message with code 0xC1900101 - 0x20017

I have tried all the guides I could find regarding the error code. So that's why I'm asking you guys.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the link to setuperr.log file (as the text here is limited to 30000 characters):
[setuperr.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2arX3raSawBWmxTMVVPdDlUOUk)

Comment: Did you tried this? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arvindsh/2015/07/07/error-0xc1900101-0x20017-upgrading-to-windows-10-build-10162/

Comment: I followed this instruction just now.
Discovered couple of Generic volumes in hidden devices.
Still same result - reboots, displays Windows 10 logo, trying to boot, and shutdowns in the end

Comment: Also, there were volume shadow copies, which I also deleted.
But two Generic volumes still reappear after restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft explained the error code in [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3107983)

> This error occurs because a driver STOP error occurs during the
>   Windows 10 upgrade.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> - Make sure all that drivers are updated.
> - Open the `Setuperr.log` and `Setupact.log` files under the `%windir%\Panther` directory, and then locate the problem drivers.
> - Update or uninstall the problem drivers.

So, this is a driver issue. Update all drivers, boot in clean mode (stopping all 3rd party tools) and next try to update.

Comment: that's exactly my problem, that it doesn't show any filenames related to devices...

Comment: share the logs and also try to update each driver. the upgrade can also fail if the partitions are encrypted with disk encrypter tools (Veracrypt, truecrypt)

Comment: I have added the link to logfile into main post.
And I don't use any encryption

Comment: this can be also chipset/SATA driver issues. try different drivers

Comment: what exactly do you mean, different drivers? different version?

Comment: in any case, there are no Chipset or SATA drivers on ASUS download page for this model... I even tried to do this using Driver Agent, which downloaded driver, but it in turn couldn't find any installable components...

Comment: go to device manager and if you see AMD/Intel SATA controller, go to update driver and select the Microsoft standard controller.

Comment: Nope, I see Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller...

Comment: ok, you run in IDE mode. change to AHCI: http://winaero.com/blog/switch-from-ide-to-achi-after-installing-windows-7-or-windows-8/ and try now to update to Windows 10

Comment: Still seeing Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller, although in BIOS it is set to AHCI, and in registry I changed DWORD to 0.
Will try the update now

Comment: Unfortunately, still no luck...
Still Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller in Device Manager.
And I was wrong about BIOS - there is no such option (AHCI/IDE), although I have latest version.
And my drive is SATA, so laptop does support SATA

Comment: Anyone? No solution?

Comment: I have no idea. try the version 1607 which will be released today

Comment: get a 1607 ISO (http://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557) and try again to update

Comment: I did, same problem.
I also tried a fresh install (changing the HDD), same problem, shows loading screen then just switches off. (Windows 10 Education 1607 this time)

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Phone the MS support

Comment: I also tried to do fresh install of Windows 8.1, getting a blue screen after Windows loading screen...